# ERROR in android studio of Multiple entries with same key

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

ERROR: Multiple entries with same key: android:appComponentFactory=REPLACE and android:appComponentFactory=REPLACE

this error comes when i try to sync the gradle.
this error  is after i updated android studio to latest version

**here is mainfest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.hoogle.news">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_app"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_app_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
        tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory,android:appComponentFactory,android:appComponentFactory">
        <activity
            android:name=".FullscreenActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".isNetworkAvailable"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen">


            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen">

                  <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: search for duplicated setting `android:appComponentFactory` in your manifest file and remove it

Comment: can you post you Manifest file here?

Comment: check the mainfest @Ananth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just delete this line under application to solve multiple error entries and merged mainfest error

tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory,android:appComponentFactory,android:appComponentFactory">